# ReferenceError: dokan_assets_url is not defined

Tags: plugins

after I installed Dokan Pro plugin there is problem in editor tools on new post and new products
this is the file dokan-tmc-button.js that has problem

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.dokan_button', {
        init : function(editor, url) {
                var menuItem = [];
                var ds_img = dokan_assets_url +'/images/D.png';
                $.each( dokan_shortcodes, function( i, val ){
                    var tempObj = {
                            text : val.title,
                            onclick: function() {
                                editor.insertContent(val.content)
                            }
                        };

                    menuItem.push( tempObj );
                } );
                // Register buttons - trigger above command when clickeditor
                editor.addButton('dokan_button', {
                    title : 'Dokan shortcodes', 
                    classes : 'dokan-ss',
                    type  : 'menubutton',
//                    text  : 'Dokan',
//                    image : dokan_assets_url +'/images/D.png',
                    menu  : menuItem,
                    style : ' background-size : 18px; background-repeat : no-repeat; background-image: url( '+ ds_img +' );'
                });
        },   
    });

    // Register our TinyMCE plugin

    tinymce.PluginManager.add('dokan_button', tinymce.plugins.dokan_button);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with dokan plugin.
Adding the code below to your "functions.php" (in your theme directory) will solve the problem temporarily (I hope they fix this conflict in the newer versions):

```
function dk_shortcode_script($shortcodes){

    define('DOKAN_SHORTCODES', $shortcodes);

    ?>
    <script>
        var dokan_assets_url = <?php echo json_encode( DOKAN_PRO_PLUGIN_ASSEST ) ?>;
        var dokan_shortcodes = <?php echo json_encode( DOKAN_SHORTCODES ) ?>;
    </script>
    <?php

    return $shortcodes;
}
add_filter('dokan_button_shortcodes', 'dk_shortcode_script', 10, 1);
add_action('admin_head', 'dk_shortcode_script');
```

> the code was written by Ahamed Arshad (@achchu93) in the plugin support forum.